# How Can I express in UI Path: IF Current Row = 1 and Current Row + 1 > 1

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I have an excel with more than 100 products.
In Column A I have numbers that indicate if its a complete new product or if its a similar product.

When CurrentRow in Column A = 1, then we are talking of a new product.
When The subsequent row is 2 or >1, then we are talking of similar prodcuts.
When The subsequent row is 3 or >1, the we are still talking of a simiar product.

Finally when the Current Row meets a 1 again, we are takling of a new product.

With that info I intend to do the following:

If CurrentRow = 1 and CurrentRow + 1 = 1, then we are talking of a unique product, so then we will go to link in Column C, get link, use browser take screen shot and paste in Power Point with “Templeate 1”.

If CurrentRow = 1 and CurrentRow + 1 > 1, then we are talking of a product with similar products, so then we will get link in Column C, use browser, take screen shot and paste in Power Point using “Templeat 2”.

So my problem is more with the logics of how to express:

CurrentRow and a CurrentRow +1

I tried: IF Current Row = 1 and Current Row + 1 > 1

Comment: You don't not need to look ahead in this case - as you mention, you have all the data available in the datatable.
If the CurrentRow value is 1, then it is a new product and you should use "Template 1". If the value is >1 then it is a similar product, and you should use "Template 2"

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **Read Range Workbook** or Excel Activity and store in an datatable variable(i.e Product_DT)
2. Use **For each datatable** and provide the datatable variable then inside for each.
3. Put **If activity** where the condition will be **CurrentRow("Column A")** = 1 and in Then block provide your usebrowser ,take screenshot and add to powerpoint.This will get all the new products in column A (you have to use that column name).
4. In else block use the provide your usebrowser ,take screenshot and add to powerpoint.

Just check for CurrentRow = 1 will do the work for your use case.